# Error: No Commands supplied when trying to install pyglet

Tags: python

I have downloaded pyglet, but when I
run the "setup.py" thing, it just says this in the
command line:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\PythonX\Include\pyglet\pyglet-1.1.4\setup.py", line 285, in
>
> ```
> setup(**setup_info)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
>
> ```
> raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
> ```
>
> SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2
>   [cmd2_opts] ...]
>
> or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
>
> or: setup.py --help-commands
>
> or: setup.py cmd --help
>
> error: no commands supplied

How do I fix this error and install pyglet?

Answer (score 42):

If you just did `python setup.py`, you'll get this - you need to type `python setup.py build` followed by `python setup.py install`.

As you are on Windows; even the above commands may not work correctly. In that case, you can [download the Windows installer version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyglet) which will install the library to your default system Python.

Comment: @theSilentOne: It said i required 1.4 or later.

Comment: Who is "it" that said that?

Comment: @Hissing Cockroach, check the other links I posted. Pick the Python installer for the architecture of your windows machine.

Comment: The window still said I had to have 2.4 or later, even after I downloaded 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the pyglet website, there is an msi installer found on their main page:

http://pyglet.googlecode.com/files/pyglet-1.1.4.msi

You'll also need to install a recent version of python

Here's the 64 bit installer:

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.amd64.msi

and the 32 bit installer:

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.msi

Comment: He is trying to install it, not run it.

Comment: None of these commands work on either command line or command prompt. They all are either invalid syntax or 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you check that link, the pyglet devs say that it doesn't need to be installed; it's portable.

Comment: Yes, I read that, but can anyone tell me how to download/get/whatever pyglet?

Comment: Check my edit, they have an msi installer on their download page. Did you try that?

Comment: Please just look at my edit, it shows you how to get pyglet and how to get python.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It worked fine when i installed on my desktop but when i wanted to install on my laptop it gave me the error message.
Solution:
Remove Python installation and reinstall again then proceed with setup of django.
* First run the command to build: setup.py build
* then run the command to install: setup.py install

This would solve your problem. But if it persists, get the msi installer

Answer (score 0):

Try this if trying on Windows7:
Add environment variable in windows
Windows+Pause > Advanced Sys Settings > Environment Variables
Add New under system variables:
Variable: Python34
Value: c:\Python34\python.py (or whereever u have installed Python)

then run using cmd:
c:\Python34>python setup_bs4.py install (setup_bs4.py-> is BS4 setup file copied here)

and done... :)
Hope it helps.